# Is there any way to transfer reputation other than bounties?

Tags: feature-request

Are there any ways to transfer reputation between users without using bounties?

Comment: I would hope not - it would be abused immediate by the puppeteers, ring-voters and other immoral abusers on SO, just as bounties are.

Answer (score 10):

> Are there any ways to transfer reputation between users without using bounties?

No there aren't, and abusing bounties that way is frowned upon.